# Fill 2D ArrayList from MySql C#

Tags: c#, mysql, arraylist

I am trying to retrieve data from MySql Database table

```
Date,     Price    
5/5/1998  93.5$    
10/5/1998 97.6$
```

and store them in an ArrayList or List in order to make some statistical calculations.

```
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;";
MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);

MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("Select Date,AnnualPrice from db_og.historicprices;", conDataBase);

MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdDataBase);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

mySqlDA.Fill(dt);

List<string> data = new List<string>();

           if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)

           {
               foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)

                   data.Add(drow["Date"].ToString());

            }
```

Comment: What is the question ???

Comment: Hi Partha and thanks for your reply! I am trying to fill a 2d arraylist or list but i dont know hot to do it in order to use the stored data for statistical calculations. So how can i save my tables data to an arraylist?

Comment: http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/167129/How-to-create-two-dimensional-ArrayList-using-C-Net/